# Named outlets not displaying content

Tags: angular

I'm attempting to use a named router outlet like so:

```
// Proposal_Year_Root_Component
<router-outlet name='popup'></router-outlet>

<ng-container *ngIf=is_ready>
  <div fxLayout=row>
    ...blah blah
```

My routes look like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: Proposal_Routing_Component,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: Proposals_Root_Component,
      },
      {
        path: ':proposal_id',
        component: Proposal_Root_Component,
        children: [
          {
            path: 'years/:year_id',
            component: Proposal_Year_Root_Component,
            children: [
              {
                path: 'scale',
                outlet: 'popup',
                loadChildren: () => import('../scale/scale.module').then(m => m.Scale_Module)
              }
            ]
          },
        ]
      },

    ]
  }
]
```

This route works and is visible in the URL:

```
...Y7BsIwXMzEGNmm7a2U4K/years/Gr1THwjaofVaB0aeRtFm/(popup:scale)
```

The only problem is that the component from the `Scale_Module` does not load as intended. This is the router outlet inside the `Proposal_Year_Root_Component`:

[image]

I've included an imported routing module with the `Scale_Module`, and a basic component at the `''` path, so the component should be displaying.

```
// Scale_Module
import { Common_Module } from '@app/modules'
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { Scale_Component } from './scale.component'
import { Scale_Routing_Module } from './scale.routing.module'

@NgModule({
  declarations: [Scale_Component],
  imports: [
    Common_Module,
    Scale_Routing_Module,
  ],
})
export class Scale_Module { }




// Scale_Routing_Module
import { Scale_Component } from './scale.component'
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router'
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: Scale_Component,
  }
]

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
})
export class Scale_Routing_Module { }
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: another clue - the `Scale_Module` is loaded in the network tab upon lazy loading. So, it's loading, it's just not displaying in the named outlet.

Comment: In which component you have defined router-outlet?

Comment: @VimalPatel it's in the `Proposal_Year_Root_Component`